# How to turn off auto add escape character feature in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ssh, escaping

I am trying to pass a command to a remote server using ssh. while my commands have some characters like `"`, `$`, `'`, `\` which often requires a backslash as a escape character except `'` (single quote), but the system is automatically taking an escape character `\` before the single codes while execution. Can some one help me how to turn off this.

OS : RHEL

my Code :

```
ssh -q $server "ps -ef | grep mongo | grep conf | awk '{print \$(NF-2)}'
```

While execution, the code becomes

```
ssh -q $server "ps -ef | grep mongo | grep conf | awk \'{print $(NF-2)}\'"
```

I need to turn off this feature

Comment: Are you saying your first command isn't working?

Comment: do you have shell debugging with `set -vx` turned on? If so, this behavior is normal. Else I'd be interested to know how  you are "seeing" this issue, maybe edit your Q to show how we can see the same thing too? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis isn't really correct. Anyhow, there is no particular reason to run Awk remotely, or `grep` at all here (because Awk does all of that nicely and efficiently with a very minor refactoring):

```
ssh -q "$server" ps -ef |
# This runs locally instead
awk '/mongo/ && /conf/ {print $(NF-2)}'
```

Comment: One reason to run `awk` remotely is if it filters *a lot* of data, to avoid unnecessarily transferring data across the connection that will just be discarded.